# toString() method returning incorrect hierarchy

Tags: javascript, oop

```html
getString(comment) {
    const authorName = comment.getAuthor().getName();
 if (!comment.getRepliedTo()) return authorName;
 return `${comment.getMessage()} by ${authorName} (replied to ${this.getString(comment.getRepliedTo())})`;
  }
  toString() {
    const authorName = this.getAuthor().getName();
    if (!this.getRepliedTo()) {
      return `${this.message} by ${authorName}`;
    }
    return this.getString(this);
  }
```

I'm trying to meet the following conditions :

When converting to a string (toString), the following format is used:
No replied to:
message + " by " + author.name
With replied to:
message + " by " + author.name + " (replied to " + repliedTo.author.name + ")"

But i keep failing the test with this message:
The toString method should return the correct hierarchy (no reply)

Comment: the issue I see is if whatever `comment` is doesn't have a `.getRepliedTo` method then `if (!comment.getRepliedTo()) return authorName;` will fail ... you'd want to test if `comment.getRepliedTo` exists before trying to execute it - since comment is the original `this` when called `return this.getString(this);` - but is something else when called `this.getString(comment.getRepliedTo())` .... one suggestion is `if (!(comment.getRepliedTo && comment.getRepliedTo()))`

Comment: javascript already has a `.toString()` method which is a class method called without params (`1234.toString()` === '1234') , perhaps you have a naming conflict if this method you made is a also class method where you call it as `something.toString()` ? try renaming it.